# Add radio button to jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to jasper and have created some reports. My requirement is i want to add radio button  to my report. By default the report displays the values in pie chart. When user click on radio button the values of the pie chart will change to percentages. Can any body help me out to achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about JR Server?

Comment: Yes. I am talking about JR server. Do you have any idea how to add the radio button?